# Convert bunch of list items (got from scaping vertical table) into pandas dataframe of equal headers and row and ultimately save as csv or excel

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, html-table, export-to-csv

I was scraping a website for data on a company and so far what I get as final result is bunch of string items which were converted into list.

Code snippet:

```
for tr in tables.find_all("tr"):
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        lists = td.text.split('\n')
```

now if, I print this `lists` with index and value using enumerate, I get 16 items as per the table scrapped which is correct if checked as per the website.

Result of `print(lists)` using `enumerate`:

```
Index   Data
0   ['XYZ']
1   ['100DL20C201961']
2   ['Capital']
3   ['12345']
4   ['Age']
5   ['16 Years']
6   ['Text']
7   ['56789']
8   ['Company Status']
9   ['Active']
10  ['Last Date']
11  ['27-11-2021']
12  ['Class']
13  ['Public Company']
14  ['Date']
15  ['31-12-2021']
```

However what I want to achieve is saving these bunch of list items as csv or excel so that every even number is header for the column name and odd number is data for the row.

**Question:**

1. Is pandas DataFrame needed for this?
2. How to convert bunch of lists as above *(or strings)* into a '.csv' or '.xlsx' table

***Summary of goal:*** -
A (2 row x 8 columns) table in .csv or .xlsx format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.instafinancials.com/company/mahan-energen-limited/U40100DL2005PLC201961"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

data = []
d = dict((row.select_one('td:nth-child(1)').get_text(),row.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').get_text()) for row in soup.select('#companyContentHolder_companyHighlightsContainer>table >tbody tr')[:8])
#print(d)
    
data.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
#print(df)
```

[image]

**Complete ResulSet**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.instafinancials.com/company/mahan-energen-limited/U40100DL2005PLC201961"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

data = []
d = dict((row.select_one('td:nth-child(1)').get_text(),row.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').get_text()) for row in soup.select('#companyContentHolder_companyHighlightsContainer>table >tbody tr')[:8])
#print(d)

d.update(dict((row.select_one('td:nth-child(3)').get_text(),row.select_one('td:nth-child(4)').get_text()) for row in soup.select('#companyContentHolder_companyHighlightsContainer>table >tbody tr')[:8])) 
data.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('out2.csv',index=False)
#print(df)
```

Comment: Hello @F.Hoque. Thank you giving a solution to this. I tried this however, the headers are captured correctly but row is getting captured as new line item instead right under the headers. Am I doing something wrong? Here is [link to image](https://ibb.co/C0kYZdQ) of `Out.csv` file.

Comment: Would you share the url? Then it would be really easy to solve the issue

Comment: Hello @F.Hoque, Thanks again. Here is the url for actual data :) - [link to URL](https://www.instafinancials.com/company/mahan-energen-limited/U40100DL2005PLC201961) and here is the [table](https://ibb.co/1zbbjsr), that I am trying to capture in CSV/xlsx

Comment: @Drp RD, see the update output

Comment: Hello @F.Hoque. Bravo. Thanks for answer with complete tweak for scraping above site. If it is not too much to ask, how you one can get to know which `nth child` to target in this case.

Comment: Each row contains 4tds and 1st and 2d,3rd and 4th which I have made key value pairs by selecting css  selectors nth-child slicing techinique and put it into a dict by thinking a bit depth. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248372/discussion-between-drp-rd-and-f-hoque).